# Why do some errors in Visual Studio disappear?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debug

When debugging a project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional, I built the project, resulting in about 15 errors. But as I scroll through the file containing the errors, some of the errors disappear in the error list (without changing the file at all). A few seconds later, those errors will re-appear in the error list.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this is usually VS2010 taking a little while the parse through your code. It is more apparent when you correct an error in code, but VS insists that the error is still present even if you remove the entire line of offending code. Rebuilding the project will correct the "false" error in this scenario. I'm thinking your seeing the opposite effect of this.

Comment: This is causing it to go back and forth? Because it'll do it once, I'll scroll through (Still not making any changes), and it'll do it again later

Comment: What type of project are you working on?

Comment: It's in C++, if that's what you mean. Windows application